# Remove duplicate element depending the user parameters in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I try to remove duplicates words in multiples categories. For this, I have an object named users which contains the words that user sends.

And I use a new object that contains the words found in dictionary with its category.

```js
const Themes = {
    Animals: [
        'ZOE',
        'ZEBRA'
    ],
    Names: [
        'ZOE'
    ]
}

let users = []
let increment = 0
let copyArr = []

checkProposition()

function checkProposition() {
  users.push({
    id: '1',
    words: ['ZOE', 'ZEBRA'],
    score: 0
  })
  users.forEach(user => {
    copyArr.push({
      id: user.id,
      wordsFound: [],
      saveCategory: []
    })
    user.words.forEach(word => {
      algorithmCore(word)
    })
    increment++
  })
  console.log(copyArr)
}

function algorithmCore(word) {
  for (var key in Themes) {
    for (var answer in Themes[key]) {
      if (word == Themes[key][answer]) {
        copyArr[increment].wordsFound.push(word)
        copyArr[increment].saveCategory.push(key)
      }
    }
  }
  return
}
```

Output copyArr

```
{ id: '1', wordsFound: [ 'ZOE', 'ZOE', 'ZEBRA' ], saveCategory: [ 'Animals', 'Names', 'Animals' ]}
```

Expected output :

```
{ id: '1', wordsFound: [ 'ZOE', 'ZEBRA' ], saveCategory: [ 'Names', 'Animals' ]}
```

And it should be : ZOE (Names) ZEBRA (Animals)

If User sends :

```
users.push({
    id: '1',
    words: ['ZOE', 'ZOE'],
    score: 0
})
```

It should be :

```
{ id: '1', wordsFound: [ 'ZOE', 'ZOE' ], saveCategory: [ 'Names', 'Animals' ]}
```

But if user sends :

```
users.push({
    id: '1',
    words: ['ZOE', 'ZOE', 'ZEBRA'],
    score: 0
})
```

It should be:

```
{ id: '1', wordsFound: [ 'ZOE', 'ZOE' ], saveCategory: [ 'Names', 'Animals' ]}
or
{ id: '1', wordsFound: [ 'ZOE', 'ZEBRA' ], saveCategory: [ 'Names', 'Animals' ]}
```

Comment: you wrote: "And it should be : ZOE (Names) ZEBRA (Animals)".
why ZOE(Names) and not ZOE(Animals) ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the game named "Petit bac". The user has to send words depending to a letter. He can only use one word per category. If the user sends only one time "zoe", it should be "names" because zebra is used for "animals". If "zoe" is the animal, what do we want with "zebra" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a map instead with the possible matched words for each category,
then for each category if it has more than one word filter each word depending on it's existence on other matched categories

```js
const Themes = {
  Animals: [
    'ZOE',
    'ZEBRA'
  ],
  Names: [
    'ZOE'
  ]
}

let users = []
let increment = 0
let copyArr = []
let usedAnswers = [];

checkProposition()

function checkProposition() {
  users.push({
    id: '1',
    words: ['ZOE', 'ZEBRA'],
    score: 0
  }, {
    id: '2',
    words: ['ZOE', 'ZOE'],
    score: 0
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    words: ['ZOE'],
    score: 0
  })
  users.forEach(user => {
    usedAnswers[increment] = {}
    copyArr.push({
      id: user.id,
      wordsFound: [],
      saveCategory: []
    })
    user.words.forEach(word => {
      algorithmCore(word, usedAnswers[increment])
    })

    for (var key in usedAnswers[increment]) {
      if (usedAnswers[increment][key].length > 1) {
        usedAnswers[increment][key] = usedAnswers[increment][key].filter(word => {
          for (var key1 in usedAnswers[increment]) {
            if (key !== key1 && usedAnswers[increment][key1].includes(word))
              return false;
          }
          return true;
        })
      }
    }
    
    const userWords=[...user.words];
    Object.entries(usedAnswers[increment]).forEach(([key,words])=>{
      const wordIndex=userWords.indexOf(words[0]);
      if(wordIndex >= 0){
        userWords.splice(wordIndex,1);
        copyArr[increment].wordsFound.push(words[0])
        copyArr[increment].saveCategory.push(key)
      }
    })

    increment++
  })
  console.log(copyArr)
}

function algorithmCore(word, used) {
  for (var key in Themes) {
    for (var answer in Themes[key]) {
      const wordKey = `${word}(${key})`;
      if (word == Themes[key][answer]) {
        used[key] = (used[key] || []);
        if (!used[key].includes(word))
          used[key].push(word)
      }
    }
  }
  return
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is exactly what i tried to do !

Comment: When the user send only one time Zoe, how could I choose only one of the list ?

Comment: you could iterate the user words and pick from the copyArr